pip install bllipparser giving issue with macos
I am getting this error when trying to install with pip install bllipparser in my python3 virtual environment.
Building wheels for collected packages: bllipparser
  Building wheel for bllipparser (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [38 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/ModelFetcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/RerankerFeatureCorpus.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/RerankingParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/JohnsonReranker.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/Utility.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/ParsingShell.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      copying python/bllipparser/CharniakParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/bllipparser
      running build_ext
      building 'bllipparser._CharniakParser' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/first-stage
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/first-stage/PARSE
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/first-stage/PARSE/swig
      Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk
      Please check your Xcode installation
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk -isysroot /path/to/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Ifirst-stage/PARSE/ -I/Volumes/HardDrive/PHENO_HPO/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c first-stage/PARSE/Bchart.C -o build/temp.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/first-stage/PARSE/Bchart.o
      clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/path/to/MacOSX10.15.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
      In file included from first-stage/PARSE/Bchart.C:17:
      In file included from first-stage/PARSE/Bchart.h:20:
      In file included from first-stage/PARSE/ChartBase.h:20:
      In file included from first-stage/PARSE/Edge.h:20:
      In file included from first-stage/PARSE/Term.h:21:
      In file included from first-stage/PARSE/ECString.h:15:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:641:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:60:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string.h:60:15: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
      #include_next <string.h>
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bllipparser
  Running setup.py clean for bllipparser
Failed to build bllipparser
ERROR: Could not build wheels for bllipparser, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Initially, I was getting the error, but that went away with changing the version to 10.15:

      Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk
      Please check your Xcode installation
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk -isysroot /path/to/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Ifirst-stage/PARSE/ -I/Volumes/HardDrive/PHENO_HPO/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c first-stage/PARSE/Bchart.C -o build/temp.macosx-13.0-x86_64-cpython-312/first-stage/PARSE/Bchart.o
      clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/path/to/MacOSX10.15.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
      clang: error: invalid version number in 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13'
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I am not very familiar with this library/setup for it, so any guidance is helpful.
Thanks,

It turns out it was only an issue with the MACOS sdk version. Upgrading the Xcode command lines tools fixed the issue.
